# Convert Images using AppleScript and Finder

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'd like to convert some specific images (jpg) to another type of image file, using AppleScript (PNG, jpg2000, or similar - should have good image quality).
The images that I want to convert are all in one folder. There are no other files in this folder, except for the images.

How can I simply tell Finder to convert all of these images to another type of image and to replace the original images in the folder?

I'm new to AppleScript and it would be very nice if someone could help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Finder doesn't know how to convert images, you will need to use something like the Preview application or a utility such as **Image Events**.  You can use AppleScript, but for this it would probably be easier to just use Automator, for example:

Create a new workflow document, and drag actions from the library:

- **Ask for Finder Items**  { Type: *Folders* }
- **Get Folder Contents**

  -- or --
- **Ask for Finder Items**  { Type: *Files*,  Allow Multiple Selections }

  -- then --
- **Change Type of Image**  { To Type: *whatever* }

The **Change Type of Image** action will ask if you want to add a **Copy Finder Items** action to make copies to work with instead of the originals.

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer. The process of converting the images will actually be part of a bigger AppleScript. Would you also use the Automator in this case? And if so, can I activate the Automator workflow using an applescript command?

Comment: Or can I for example use a tell command in applescript, which tells Automator to do several actions? - Like  "tell Automator to Ask for Finder Items" etc?

Comment: For something you can use in a larger project, I posted an AppleScript solution using **Image Events** in my answer to [another similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57807513/10853463).

Comment: All right. Thank you very much for your help! I think, I will be able to put that into action. <3

Comment: **Image Events** can save documents as BMP, JPEG, JPEG2, PICT, PNG, ,PSD, QuickTime Image, or TIFF - you can look at its scripting dictionary for other terminology.